# Identity User value is null in controller constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm using *TrackerEnabledDbContext* as a library for audit trail and also *Autofac* library for dependency injection.
I registered my DbContext in Global.asax file as
`builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();`
Then in my controller I have this code on controller constructors

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext db;

    public MyController(){}

    public MyController(MyDbContext db)
    {        
        this.db = db;
        if (db != null)
        {
            db.ConfigureUsername(() => User.Identity.Name);
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is that whenever constructor method with db context parameter is initialized, User value is null.

How to modify this codes so that whenever this controller is initialized User value could populate with user values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The user is assigned well after the controller has been created by he framework. You wont be able to access it in the constructor. Instead you should get the user id directly in your actions after the request and associated user have been assigned to the controller

Comment: This is one of the [many reasons](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) why injected services should not be used from inside the constructor. Also, the injected service should never be null. Instead of checking for null, you should verify the precondition by throwing when null.